# Simple apache redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect all images from www.example.com and example.com to images.example.com?

Here is some code I found online but I don't understand much and it doesn't work as expected

**edit**

```
#step 1 redirect ALL images from any domain to images.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|jfif|bmp|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://images.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#step 2 redirect non www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#step 3 redirect ALL non images from images.example.com to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|jfif|bmp|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Well you are trying to rewrite to www.example.com and not image.example.com, so there is that.

Comment: @Mike Brant: Thanks, I updated my code... Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this if you want to redirect all images to the subdomain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|jfif|bmp|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://images.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^images\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.+)\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|jfif|bmp|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you please provide code on how to redirect all non image requests from the domain images.example.com to www.example.com? Thanks!

Comment: Is this code corect: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|jfif|bmp|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: I updated the answer. Try to not ask mulitple questions in the same question after it's answered. Just ask another question and we'll still help you.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! If you have time please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820476/simple-mod-rewrite-redirects