# simple mod_rewrite redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After a lot of research and some help, I managed to learn a bit of how mod rewrite works... Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code bellow?

```
######redirect all static files to the static domain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|jfif|bmp|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://static.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

######redirect naked to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

######redirect IP to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^100\.100\.100\.100$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

######redirect all non static files from static domain (because that remains) to www
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|jfif|bmp|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks!

Also, what's the difference between:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.+)\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|jfif|bmp|css|js)$ [NC]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|jfif|bmp|css|js)$ [NC]
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: @anubhava: `www.example.com/image.png` is not redirected to `static.example.com/image.png`

Comment: @MainHero the first rule should do that for you. Are you saying it's not working now?

Comment: @Panama Jack: Seems like it was related to my browser... The 2nd error I am getting is endless redirects to static.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .htaccess:

```
######redirect all static files to the static domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|png|jpe?g|jfif|bmp|css|js)$ http://static.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]

######redirect naked to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^100\.100\.100\.100$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

######redirect all non static files from static domain (because that remains) to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static\. [NC]
RewriteRule !\.(gif|png|jpe?g|jfif|bmp|css|js)$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what `^(www\.)?` does?

Comment: That matches `www` optionally so matches both `www.example.com` and `example.com`

Answer (score 1):

Based off our previous conversation. You can also combine the `www` and `IP` rule. It only needs to check if `www` is not there.

```
######redirect naked to www or IP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

######redirect all static files to the static domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|jfif|bmp|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://static.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

######redirect all non static files from static domain (because that remains) to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^images\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.+)\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|jfif|bmp|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301
```

This is other way.